# Retag request: boi-antibirth -> boir-antibirth

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

I was reviewing the tag wiki submissions for what I thought was [boir-antibirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boir-antibirth), but upon closer inspection, was actually [boi-antibirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boi-antibirth).

This is an issue, because the [Antibirth mod](http://antibirth.gamepedia.com/The_Binding_of_Isaac:_Antibirth_Wiki) is specifically for the Binding of Isaac: Rebirth (BoIR), and *not* for the original Binding of Isaac (BoI). The way the tag is currently written makes it appear to be for the original Binding of Isaac rather than the Rebirth version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tag name is consistent with [boi-afterbirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boi-afterbirth) and [boi-afterbirth+](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boi-afterbirth%2b), both of which are expansions for The Binding of Isaac: Rebirth. I think changing the tag name is unnecessary.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I thought those were formatted differently.